1960s-70s movie in color; Human reactions being tested before assistance provided
I'm not clear if this was a film or series, but I don't remember the characters in anything else. That wouldn't rule out something like The Twilight Zone, but my memory was that it was more than an hour long, so I'm assuming a movie. Maybe made for TV? In color, made in the 60s or 70s. The film had one of those "learn a lesson" or "morality" elements that seem more common to the 50s & 60s than the 70s, but I'm basing my guess of the decade only from when I think I would have watched it. I remember the film having a comic relief element (like Estelle Winwood in The Magic Sword) but I can't recall any cast members. I have no memory of it being a foreign film dubbed into English; the actors were speaking English, and I'd bet that it was American-made.
Sets were constructed, sound stage style. I don't recall anything looking realistic/natural or anything that might have been a location shot for any of the interiors of the film. The look was ... what's the technical term ... "cheesy". Much more like Forbidden Planet than The Day The Earth Stood Still. SciFi in the 1970s was looking much better, so another vote for a 1950s-60s film.
Plot... something; it's too spotty to call it a plot summary: Aliens are coming to earth, and human scientists/military (3-5 people?) have somehow gone to an alien ship/station between the earth and the invading fleet. I have a very vague memory that there was a woman on the team, but I wouldn't bet a nickel on that. The humans are attempting to pass tests in order to activate the ship and stop the invasion. I remember one of the tests involved whether or not to attack a Bug-Eyed-Monster, or give it a piece of food, and the humans decide that they should not attribute "evil" to a being simply because it is "ugly", and so they give the BEM some kind of food, and that passes the test. I'm pretty sure the word xenophobia is not used. But it is clear that the lesson is 'reason and science are better than military and guns', and 'why do we tend to attack what we don't understand?'
I can't remember if the tests themselves are later revealed to be a simulation, or if passing the tests reveals that the invasion is a simulation, or if passing the tests actually does something to stop the invasion. Again, a very hazy memory of the ship/station in the middle halting the progress of the invaders but I wouldn't bet on it. I do remember the team returning to Earth having succeeded.
I've looked through a bunch of lists of "science fiction films of the 1950s" and the like on Wikipedia, and my guess is that the title isn't a good clue to this plot. It's not Earth vs. The Flying Saucers, Invasion of the Saucer Men, Journey to the Seventh Planet, Rocket Attack U.S.A..

This is The Terrornauts (1967).
Notably, the scientists are required to conduct a series of tests on board a spaceship




In the film, a group of scientists, trying to contact aliens, are spirited away to a space station where, after a series of tests conducted by a strange alien robotic creature, they find themselves on a floating fortress in space defending the Earth from a group of invisible invaders in red spaceships known only as ‘the Enemy’.


